# Setting a CSS rule based on a selection in a drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have text boxes and drop downs pairs whose id is generated dynamically.  I'm trying to set the css rule (class) on the text box based on a selection in the drop down.  I have a the index on the drop down which is what is used to derive the id of the dropdown dynamically.  How do I set the CSS rule on the text boxes.  If I try to set the class using JavaScript, the change doesn't reflect till I refresh the page.

I'm open to use plain javascript or jquery or a mix of both.

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: Aren't you able to use descendant selectors to target them? 

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to your select so you can select them with jQuery easier.

```
<div>
    <select id="Generated1234" class="cssRule">
        <option value="class1">Class #1</option>
        <option value="class2">Class #2</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="Generated1234_text"/>
</div>
```

jQuery code, assuming your input textbox is a sibling of the select. You may need to change the last line to select the correct textbox.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select.cssRule').change(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var className = $this.val();
        $this.siblings('input[type=text]').attr('class', className);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like;

HTML;

```
<select id="selectoptions" class="cssRule">
        <option class="class1" value="red">red</option>
        <option class="class2" value="blue">blue</option>
    </select>
<input id="mytext" type="text" name="mytext"/>
```

JavaScript;
//wrap the code inside in document.ready.function

```
$("select").change(function () {
    var color = $("#selectoptions").val();
    $("#mytext").css("background",color);
});
```

CSS;

```
#mytext{
    background:red;
}
```

Here is a **[Working Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qRJnE/)**